# Reverse Domain Name Notation in NetBeans IDE 8.1 - not allowed?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've just tried to rename a JAVA package, in NetBeans IDE 8.1 (JDK 1.7), from "xy" to "com.xy.java8.packagename" but as soon as I enter the first dot I get the error message "com." is not a valid folder name.....any ideas for me ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The packagename can not end with a dot. You have to enter the complete new packagename

Comment: com.xy.java8.packagename should be the name it doesn't end with a dot.

Comment: but you have enterd `com.` then the error message will shoan. if you enter the next char the message will be gone

Comment: it doesn't :) leider

Comment: can you add a screenshot please?

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/45d2czelz/

Comment: loks like you rename the Folder not the package?

Comment: hm, it looks like it doesn't matter what I choose, NetBeans always creates a folder instead of a package when clicking new package....

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/5rfcp6hpt/

Answer (score 0):

Actually . refers to hierarchy of packages. So you can make package com and then inside com you can make xy package and so on.

Comment: I have a video tutorial where the teacher, using NetBeans IDE 7.0.1, easily renames the first and only package after the standard "Source Packages" folder from "autos" to "com.video2brain.java7....." without any error messages